# How to generate a sentence around words in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I know that how to generate next word in keras with lstm but how to predict previous word for example If you have two words like "car" and "running" then It should generate "The car is running". How can we do this in keras ?
I want to also make sure that generator should stop after completing the sentence.
Thank you.

Comment: I think this question is better asked on [datascience.stackexchange.com](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/), where a similar question already exists - [Generate new sentences based on keywords](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/60261/generate-new-sentences-based-on-keywords).

To the best of my knowledge, what you are trying to accomplish is an active area of research with no simple general solution. See [Zhang et al., POINTER: Constrained progressive text generation via insertion-based generative pre-training.](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.00558)

Comment: Hi @BoyanHristov Thanks for mentioning that website. I posted this same question there.